# Remove all #div id from domtree with class .selected

Tags: javascript

How to remove all divs with id `#divs` with class `.something` with vanilla javascript.

For example:

```
function removeEl() {
var removeEl = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
if (removeEl.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < removeEl.length; i++) { 
        var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
        elem.remove();

    }
}
```

}

This will delete all div box1 but I want to delete all box1 with class `.selected`

Comment: [IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) are unique identifier....

Comment: did you try removeEl.remove(); ?

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same ID

Comment: First off, there should only be one of each with a given `id`, second, if you still have them, use the attribute selector together with the `class`, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('[id=box1].selected');`

Comment: function removeEl() {
var removeEl = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links--link');
if (removeEl.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < removeEl.length; i++) { 
        //var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
        removeEl[i].parentNode.removeChild(removeEl[i]);

    }
}}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < removeEl.length; i++) {
    removeEl[i].remove();
}
```

You already selected all elements which you want to remove. So it's not necessary to select it again with a given id.

Comment: That's where you are wrong. OP's query is `class`, not `class` _and_ `id`, hence the one's with a given `id` is not selected.

Comment: `id=""` is unique identifier which should not used twice or more. So if you want to query for a specific identifier you have to do it by hand or having an array of ids which contain all specific ids. @LGSon: I know but i think it's more of a lack of experience problem.

Comment: It might, though in some cases there can actually be an issue, where the markup is rendered elsewhere and happen to have the same `id`. In a comment at the question I showed how to solve that.

Answer (score -2):

```
function removeEl() {
var removeEl = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
  if (removeEl.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < removeEl.length; i++) { 
    //var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
     removeEl[i].parentNode.removeChild(removeEl[i]);

  }
 }
}
```